# What is $\int_0 ^1 \int_x^1 \frac{f(t)}{t} \text dt \text dx $ if $\int f =1$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> Let $f$ be a Lebesgue integrable function on $[0,1]$ and $\int f = 1,$ and let
>   $$g(x) = \int_x ^1 \frac{f(t)}{t} \text dt \quad x \in [0,1].$$ Calculate the integral of $g$.

I feel like I'm supposed to use Fubini's Theorem in this question but I'm a bit confused about the setup. Also since the problem should work for any $f$ I took a very simple function and calculated it to be $1$ so I think that should be the answer.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Change the order of integration

Comment: @ShubhamJohri so $\int_x^1 \int_0^1 \frac{f(t)}{t} dx dt$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Draw the area of integration and observe that
$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{x}^{1} h(t,x) dt dx = \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{t} h(t,x) dx dt.$$

Comment: what is $g(t,x)$?

Comment: Any function of $t$ and $x$. In your case, $h(t,x) = \frac{f(t)}{t}$.

Comment: Changed the integrand to $h(t,x)$ as $g(x)$ (although a function of a single variable) was already in the question

Comment: Thanks @ShubhamJohri

Comment: before switching the limits, you need to check Tonelli.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!